# @Html.EditorFor helper classes is not added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC4 application in that I am using @Html.EditorFor helper helper is works but Classes are not added for that input box.I am trying this way

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

and also this way also,

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StartTime, new { Style:"Color:green;" })
```

Comment: You cannot add html attributes with `EditorFor()` unless your using MVC5.1 or higher. [What's New in ASP.NET MVC 5.1](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using @Html.EditorFor you must use @Html.TextBoxFor for giving the css class.

for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control",@style="Color:green;" })
```

Good Luck